# why is my for loop executing an extra time in UNIX environment?

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I wrote a code that worked perfectly fine, however, once I externalized the code and transferred the code to a UNIX environment like Puttty or the MAC system console, I get an anomaly. I have a for loop that executes one extra time and it's weird. [Here is a picture of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adhVk.png)

and sorry, I'm not too sure how I can enter my code in here because my #define's become overly large when I look at the preview.

[This is a link to all the source files if it is necessary to view all of them](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/fogqne1qbdi14/assignment)

the maxEmployee.h header file only contains #define MAXEMP 40

This is the main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "maxEmployee.h"


extern void InitializeAccumulators(float* totDefr, float *totPayRate, float *totRegHrs, float *totOvtHrs, float *totGross, float *totFed, float *totSt, float *totSSI, float *totNet); //3.1 Prototype

extern void InputEmployeeData(char ln[][10+1], char fn[][10+1], float hr[], float pRate[], float defr[], int i); //3.2 Prototype

extern void CalculateGross(float hr[], float pRate[], float reghr[], float ovthr[], float gross[], int i); //3.3 Prototype

extern void calculateTaxes(float gross[], float defr[], float ft[], float st[], float ssit[], int i); //3.4 Prototype

extern void CalculateNetPay(float gross[], float defr[], float ft[], float st[], float ssit[], float netPay[], int i); //3.5 Prototype

extern void CalculateTotAvg(float pRate[], float reghr[], float ovthr[], float gross[], float ft[], float st[], float ssit[], float netPay[], float defr[], int i, float *totDefr, float *totPayRate, float *totRegHrs, float *totOvtHrs, float *totGross, float *totFed, float *totSt, float *totSSIT, float *totNet,
    float *avgDefr, float *avgPayRate, float *avgRegHrs, float *avgOvtHrs, float *avgGross, float *avgFed, float *avgSt, float *avgSSIT, float *avgNet); //3.6 Prototype

extern void PrintReportSummary(char fn[][10+1], char ln[][10+1], float pRate[], float reghr[], float ovthr[], float gross[], float ft[], float st[], float ssit[], float netPay[], float defr[], int i, float totDefr, float totPayRate, float totRegHrs, float totOvtHrs, float totGross, float totFed, float totSt, float totSSIT, float totNet,
    float avgDefr, float avgPayRate, float avgRegHrs, float avgOvtHrs, float avgGross, float avgFed, float avgSt, float avgSSIT, float avgNet); //3.7 Prototype


int main(void)

{ // 3.0
    char ln[MAXEMP][10 + 1], fn[MAXEMP][10 + 1]; //last name and first name
    float hr[MAXEMP], pRate[MAXEMP], defr[MAXEMP], gross[MAXEMP], reghr[MAXEMP], ovthr[MAXEMP]; // hour, payrate, deferred, gross, regular hour, over time hours
    float ft[MAXEMP], st[MAXEMP], ssit[MAXEMP]; //calculate taxes
    float netPay[MAXEMP];

    float totDefr, totPayRate, totRegHrs, totOvtHrs, totGross, totFed, totSt, totSSIT, totNet;
    float avgDefr, avgPayRate, avgRegHrs, avgOvtHrs, avgGross, avgFed, avgSt, avgSSIT, avgNet;
    int i, yesno = 1;


    InitializeAccumulators(&totDefr, &totPayRate, &totRegHrs, &totOvtHrs, &totGross,
        &totFed, &totSt, &totSSIT, &totNet); //call 3.1
    for (i = 0; i < MAXEMP && yesno == 1; i++)
    {
        InputEmployeeData(ln, fn, hr, pRate, defr, i); //call 3.2
        CalculateGross(hr, pRate, reghr, ovthr, gross, i); //call 3.3
        calculateTaxes(gross, defr, ft, st, ssit, i); //call 3.4
        CalculateNetPay(gross, defr, ft, st, ssit, netPay, i); //call 3.5
        printf("Do you have another employee you wish to enter? (1 = Yes, 0 = No) ");
        scanf("%d", &yesno);  
    } 
    CalculateTotAvg(pRate, reghr, ovthr, gross, ft, st, ssit, netPay, defr, i, &totDefr, &totPayRate, &totRegHrs, &totOvtHrs, &totGross, &totFed, &totSt, &totSSIT, &totNet, &avgDefr, &avgPayRate, &avgRegHrs, &avgOvtHrs, &avgGross, &avgFed, &avgSt, &avgSSIT, &avgNet); //call 3.6

    PrintReportSummary(fn, ln, pRate, reghr, ovthr, gross, ft, st, ssit, netPay, defr, i, totDefr, totPayRate, totRegHrs, totOvtHrs, totGross, totFed, totSt, totSSIT, totNet, //call 3.7
        avgDefr, avgPayRate, avgRegHrs, avgOvtHrs, avgGross, avgFed, avgSt, avgSSIT, avgNet);

    fflush(stdin), getchar(); // hold screen

    return 0;

}
```

This is the PrintReportSummary sub function:

```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <string.h>
> #include "maxEmployee.h"
> 
> #define REPORTHEADERFORMAT "\n%-20s%16.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f\n%54.2f%36.2f%18.2f\n"
> #define REPORTHEADERTOT "\nTotals%30.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f\n%54.2f%36.2f%18.2f\n"
> #define REPORTHEADERAVG "\nAverages%28.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f%18.2f\n%54.2f%36.2f%18.2f\n"
> 
> void PrintReportSummary(char fn[][10+1], char ln[][10+1], float
> pRate[], float reghr[], float ovthr[], float gross[], float ft[],
> float st[], float ssit[], float netPay[], float defr[], int i, float
> totDefr, float totPayRate, float totRegHrs, float totOvtHrs, float
> totGross, float totFed, float totSt, float totSSIT, float totNet,
>   float avgDefr, float avgPayRate, float avgRegHrs, float avgOvtHrs,
> float avgGross, float avgFed, float avgSt, float avgSSIT, float
> avgNet); //3.7 Prototype
> 
> void PrintReportSummary(char fn[][10+1], char ln[][10+1], float
> pRate[], float reghr[], float ovthr[], float gross[], float ft[],
> float st[], float ssit[], float netPay[], float defr[], int i, float
> totDefr, float totPayRate, float totRegHrs, float totOvtHrs, float
> totGross, float totFed, float totSt, float totSSIT, float totNet,
>     float avgDefr, float avgPayRate, float avgRegHrs, float avgOvtHrs, float avgGross, float avgFed, float avgSt, float avgSSIT, float
> avgNet) //3.7 {
> 
>   char fullname[MAXEMP][20+1];
> 
>   printf("Employee            Pay     Reg Hrs       Gross          Fed        SSI            
> Net\n");  printf("Name                Rate        Ovt Hrs       Pay            State            
> Defr            Pay\n");
>     printf("==============================================================================================================================");
> 
>   for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)    {   strcpy (fullname[k], ln[k]);
>   strcat(fullname[k], ", ");  strcat(fullname[k], fn[k]);
> 
>   printf(REPORTHEADERFORMAT, fullname[k], pRate[k], reghr[k], gross[k],
> ft[k], ssit[k], netPay[k], ovthr[k], st[k], defr[k]);     }
>   printf(REPORTHEADERTOT, totPayRate, totRegHrs, totGross, totFed,
> totSSIT, totNet, totOvtHrs, totSt, totDefr);  printf(REPORTHEADERAVG,
> avgPayRate, avgRegHrs, avgGross, avgFed, avgSSIT, avgNet, avgOvtHrs,
> avgSt, avgDefr); }
```

This is my make file:

```
dataReport.exe: main.o InitializeAccumulators.o InputEmployeeData.o CalculateGross.o calculateTaxes.o CalculateNetPay.o CalculateTotAvg.o PrintReportSummary.o
    g++ main.o InitializeAccumulators.o InputEmployeeData.o CalculateGross.o calculateTaxes.o CalculateNetPay.o CalculateTotAvg.o PrintReportSummary.o -o dataReport.exe

main.o: main.cpp maxEmployee.h
    g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o

InitializeAccumulators.o: InitializeAccumulators.cpp
    g++ -c InitializeAccumulators.cpp -o InitializeAccumulators.o

InputEmployeeData.o: InputEmployeeData.cpp
    g++ -c InputEmployeeData.cpp -o InputEmployeeData.o

CalculateGross.o: CalculateGross.cpp
    g++ -c CalculateGross.cpp -o CalculateGross.o

calculateTaxes.o: calculateTaxes.cpp taxrates.h
    g++ -c calculateTaxes.cpp -o calculateTaxes.o

CalculateNetPay.o: CalculateNetPay.cpp
    g++ -c CalculateNetPay.cpp -o CalculateNetPay.o

CalculateTotAvg.o: CalculateTotAvg.cpp
    g++ -c CalculateTotAvg.cpp -o CalculateTotAvg.o

PrintReportSummary.o: PrintReportSummary.cpp maxEmployee.h
    g++ -c PrintReportSummary.cpp -o PrintReportSummary.o

clean:
    rm *.o dataReport.exe
```

So then my question is how do I fix this? I've been stuck on this for a couple days now...

Comment: Did you really mean to use `<=` and not `<`?

Comment: At least under Linux this `fflush(stdin)` (flushing standard input) provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Use -O2 -W -Wall or you loose most of the warnings g++ can issue for bad code. A lot of the time undefined behaviour shows up as warnings.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. stackoverflow.com is not a distributed debugging service for huge piles of code.

Answer (score 0):

In main you loop 1 time, so the variable "i" has a value of 1 at the end of the for loop.

In PrintReportSummary you use the following loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
```

Substitute 1 for i gives:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= 1; k++)
```

So the loop body is executed 2 times. The behaviour should be the same in windows so you might re-test that :)
Furthermore, if you input 40 records, or you set MAXEMP to 1 and input 1 record, the program will crash or show undefined behaviour at the second for loop, cause it would access elements out of bounds from your arrays.

Solution: change <= to <.

To clean up the code a little you could use structs instead of that many function arguments :)